# Initialize addon

Tags: add-on

I have an addon with some modules. I would like to execute some code when I install the addon or when Blender starts if the addon is installed. I make a few custom properties, disable a few panels execute some operators etc.

I have the code in one of my modules. I tried just to have the code in the script, I tried to make an operator where the code is in invoke() and I tried to put the code under register(). All of this works when I just run the script in the editor. But none of this worked when I install the zipped package (including an **init**.py) as an addon.

Comment: You need to register a function that has the '@persistent' decoration.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do something at the time of installing put the code in `register` function. when you turn on your addon in preferences panel the register function would be called and when you turn that of the `unregister` function would be called.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. But I am calling other operators like: bpy.context.space_data.context = 'SCENE' and I get this confusing error: AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'space_data'. Is this because some other Blender stuff (operators) aren't registred yet, or something?

Comment: Because `bpy.context.space_data` really has no attribute `context` but has attribute `type` which (I guess) is what you are looking for. this is `readonly`. this link may help:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107438/how-to-set-context-to-run-operations