# Switch context to Outliner

Tags: python, outliner

I'm working on an add-on that performs some operations on items in Outliner (actually it enables me to batch rename collections, a feature missing from Blender). The addon works fine if I assign a keyboard shortcut to it, click Outliner and hit the key. However it does not work if I launch it from another window, or from the Edit menu. In these cases I receive the *'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_ids'* error.

I tried a few things found on the net, which were usually trying to get the outliner window and override the context. One is this:

```
   for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            override = bpy.context.copy()
            override['area'] = area
```

I thought I can just call `override.selected_ids` instead of `bpy.context.selected_ids`, but I cannot for an *'dict' object has no attribute 'selected_ids'* error.

Have any of you managed to find a way to switch context to Outliner?

I need a solution for Blender 2.92+

Comment: Suggest add more detail and especially what operator(s) you'd like call. At the moment you're just trying to override the context of the current area rather than switching the area to the outliner. BTW: The blender version doesn't really matter in this case. Out of curiosity: Where `selected_ids` attribute come from? Also I'd suggest take the [tour] to learn about how this site works.

Comment: Often the case need to override `space_data and region` also. 99% of qs re context override would be an example.

Comment: @brockmann, thanks for your reply. I just want to grab the objects selected in the Outliner and change their name property. As far as I learned, `selected_ids` for `bpy.context` only exists if the Outliner was the active area at the moment of starting the script. I want to be able to use it from other areas as well, and I think I first somehow need to switch to Outliner, so that I can get the result of `bpy.context.selected_ids` and process it. Let me know if I still miss something from my description.

Comment: I don't think there is something like `selected_ids`, see the search results of the api docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=selected_ids&check_keywords=yes&area=default# . Anyway, to avoid confusion I recommend just tell us what you'd like to do because you do not have to "switch" to the outliner in order to rename the selected objects... and again overriding the context and switching the ouliner is a different thing.

Comment: @brockmann, sorry but I don't get what details you miss. I can just repeat myself, I'm afraid: I want to change names of collections. Anyway, `bpy.context.selected_ids` works properly if the active area is the Outliner, and I can get the list of selected collections and objects, but if the active area is different at the moment of launching the script, `bpy.context` returns a different object, which actually does not have this property defined, and calls to it therefore cause an exception. So to be able to get the list, it seems that I have to switch to the proper context.

Comment: Get it now, had a look into the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.92/Python_API) and I found `selected_ids` as a new *undocumented* member. However, switching the current area to the outliner doesn't help much since the selection will be different to the one which is open already (see my attempts: https://pasteall.org/dTGd/raw). Also, I can't find a way to access the member from the active space unfortunately, seems unfinished to me.

Answer (score 7):

After some more digging, I figured out a better way, that is probably the way intended by the devs:

using `bpy.context.temp_override(area=override_area)` ([documentaiton page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.area))

Here is the same example as above with the new solution:

```py
#Initialize the override_area in case it does not need to be overriden
areaOverride=bpy.context.area    
if bpy.context.area.type!='OUTLINER':
    #If needed find the outliner area
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            areaOverride=area

with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areaOverride):
    #Any code you want...
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_ids:
        print(f"Selected: {obj.name} - {type(obj)}") #Notice you also get selected collections, normally impossible outside of Outliner context
```

With that, no more issues.

Comment: Note that the use of a context dictionary for an override is deprecated in 3.2 and scheduled to be removed in 3.3, both to be replaced by [`context.temp_override()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override).

Comment: @MartyFouts I am sorry, I don't have that much experience in python. Could you develop? For example, if we use context.temp_override(override_area) we would no longer have access to its "selected_ids" property? 

> `both to be replaced by context.temp_override()`

Is that not what I am doing in that code sample above? You seem to imply that this solution will no longer be supported in 3.3

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267435/42221) and the one it mentions and [this section of the manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) for an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same situation I wanted to reach `selected_ids` from another context than the *Outliner*, and it looks like you can use this solution: [how to set context to run operations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107438/how-to-set-context-to-run-operations)

It is a hack, this solution consists in:

- Put the outliner in full screen (Forcing the active context to the Outliner)
- You execute your code in `OUTLINER` context
- You revert the action of putting the Outliner in fullscreen.
  Since it all happens in one frame, the user does not see that the outliner was in full screen.

**Noticeable issues:**

- The header of the originally active window context blinks for 1 frame.
- The collection scrolls vertical scroll gets to its lower position. If anyone figure out a way to prevent that, or reset the scrolls, I would love to hear. (Impossible to use the outliner operators after the view is reverted.)

Here is an example of how to use it:

````py
def setOutlinerContext():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            override = bpy.context.copy()
            override['area'] = area
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override, use_hide_panels=False)

def MyFunctionExecutedOutsideOutlinerContext:
    setOutlinerContext() 
    #At this point the Outliner is in full screen and is the active context

    #Execute your code... For example:
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_ids:
        print(f"Selected: {obj.name} - {type(obj)}") #Notice you also get selected collections, normally impossible outside of Outliner context

    #Important: now revert the UI to its original state
    bpy.ops.screen.back_to_previous() 
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Since Blender 4.0 JulienH's method stopped working - now Blender is also requiring to override the region, not just the area.

```
import bpy

def get_outliner_area():
    if bpy.context.area.type!='OUTLINER':
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
                return area

area = get_outliner_area()
region = next(region for region in area.regions if region.type == "WINDOW")

with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area, reigon=region):
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_ids:
        print(f"Selected: {obj.name} - {type(obj)}")
```