# blender scripting function bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled() not running correctly

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

For some reason the function stated in the title is not running when I tell it to run. I am trying to make it apply some texture baked images onto my object using python scripting but it simply isnt running without giving me an error. The error comes from farther down the code when I am trying to connect certain nodes that have been added however as the function is not running the nodes dont exist and it gives me an attribute error stating 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outputs'. If anybody can help it would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

```
    win = bpy.context.window
    scr = win.screen
    areas  = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR']
    regions = [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']
    
    #global directory
    #global imgName
    directory = 'C:\\stable internship\\Programming'
    filepath = directory + '\\'
    objectName = 'myod'
    filesToTexture = [{"name": objectName +  "_normal.png", "name": objectName + "_normal.png"}, {"name": objectName + "_specular.png", "name": objectName + "_specular.png"}, {"name": objectName + "_roughness.png", "name": objectName + "_roughness.png"}, {"name": objectName + "_color.png", "name": objectName + "_color.png"}]

    print(filesToTexture)
    print(filepath)
    print(objectName)
    with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win,area=areas[0], region=regions[0],screen=scr):
        print("IS THIS WORKING")
        bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled(filepath=filepath, directory=filepath,files=filesToTexture, relative_path=True)
    
    material = bpy.context.active_object.active_material

    base_color_texture_node = None
    for node in material.node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and node.label.startswith('Base Color'):
            base_color_texture_node = node
            break

    material.node_tree.links.new(base_color_texture_node.outputs['Alpha'], principled_bsdf_node.inputs['Alpha'])
```

[image]

Earlier in my code I set up everything already for the function including having the shader editor open and use nodes on so that the function can add the textures. However, after running my program it stays exactly the same and it gives me an attribute error.

[image]

Comment: maybe see [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267380/why-does-nw-add-textures-for-principled-work-w-existing-material-but-not-w-d) for an example usage of `bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled`. it works in this case.

Comment: I already saw that thread several times and actually copied the code several times from there. The problem is that I think that I am taking the file path from a user prompt whereas in that thread the filepath is built into the code. I just think there is an error with my filepath and directory but do not know how to fix it.